# ListView getCount() method off by one iteration

Tags: java, android, listview

I am running into an issue with the `getCount()` function that is provided with `ListView`. I am trying to get the number of rows that are displayed in a `ListView` when I filter them with `onQueryTextChange()` method provided by `SearchView`. Unfortunately, **the number I get is always off by one iteration**. For example, If I start off with 4 items in the `ListView` and filter it so that there should only be 1 item in the `ListView` the `getCount()` function returns 4 even though I want 1. If I change the filter up again right after that then I get 1. How do I get it so that when I filter a `ListView` in the `onQueryTextChange()` method, the appropriate `getCount()` number will be given?

```
@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

    sizeOfList = listView.getAdapter().getCount(); //changes based on the number of items in the listview....so changes when filtered
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), String.valueOf(sizeOfList), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newText)){
        listView.clearTextFilter();

        for (int i = 0; i < actualposList.size(); i++){
            listView.setItemChecked(actualposList.get(i), true);
            Log.d("qqqq", String.valueOf(actualposList.get(i)));
        }

    } else {

        listView.setFilterText(newText);

        if (!actualposList.isEmpty()){
            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
                //listView.setItemChecked(i, false);
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: cant you use actualposList.size() instead of getCount ?

Comment: Unfortunately not, actualposList holds the position of the checked items in my dialog that I create. I need the number of items that appear in the listview when onQueryTextChange is called.

Comment: You may try: Method1 - instead of using filter, use a public method inside your adapter. Method2 - create interface in your adapter and in filter's publishResults(), update your activity/ fragment [you may take a look of my sample in array adapter here: http://programandroidlistview.blogspot.com/]. Hope that help!

Answer (score 0):

can you show what clearFilterText and setFilterText do?  If they modify the list in any way you need to call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged so that the changes are reflected in the adapter

Comment: I am using a searchView inside a dialog to filter a listView that is in the same dialog. So `clearFilterText()` shows the entire list of items in the listView, while `setFilterText(newText)` only shows items in the listView that conform to the newText that was passed in.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newText)) {
        listView.clearTextFilter();

        for (int i = 0; i < actualposList.size(); i++) {
            listView.setItemChecked(actualposList.get(i), true);
            Log.d("qqqq", String.valueOf(actualposList.get(i)));
        }

    } else {

        listView.setFilterText(newText);

        if (!actualposList.isEmpty()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                //listView.setItemChecked(i, false);
            }
        }
    }
    sizeOfList = listView.getAdapter().getCount(); //changes based on the number of items in the listview....so changes when filtered
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), String.valueOf(sizeOfList), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    return true;
}
```

Comment: I've tried doing this and I get the same result unfortunately :(